# Can Stata help files be version specific?

Tags: documentation, stata

Stata's ado packages quite nicely accommodate end users running different versions of Stata. For example:

```
program define MyGreatProgram

  if int(_caller())<8 {
    display as res "MyGreatProgram does not support this version of Stata, sorry."
    exit
  }
  else {
    if int(_caller())<14 {
      MyGreatProgram8 `0'
    }
    else { 
      MyGreatProgram14 `0'
    }
  } 
  end
```

Stata's improvements with newer versions have extended to improving the possibilities in help files. For example, in Stata versions 14+, one can incorporate Unicode, and this may be very helpful in documentation (e.g., Greek characters, mathematical operators, etc.). However, in my code above, an end user of MyGreatProgram running Stata version 11, would not find help files with Unicode especially legible, while a user running Stata 15 might think they looked just fine.

**Is it possible to have Stata automatically recognize separate help files for different versions of Stata, or to embed version-specific directives into Stata `.sthlp` files?**

Comment: I hope my use of the `[documentation]` tag is appropriate here. I realize I am not asking a question about algorithmic document generation, self-documenting code: I am asking about manual generation of documentation. I am receptive to instruction and editing. :)

Comment: I am not aware of any such thing.  You could distribute multiple help files. Note that it's only convention that a command has a help file with same stem name, but a convention that is widely followed and expected.

Comment: Thank you @NickCox That gives a clue for one clunky but manageable kinda solution as in my answer.

Comment: In practice I don't try to be bang up-to-date in exploiting what is possible, as I try to think of people who (whose institutions) can't afford to keep up-to-date.

Comment: @NickCox **Absolutely.** One of my affiliate institutions has Stata 10 in our student labs (the other is up to date, though, so that's good :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by @NickCox suggests the following kinda clunky, but definitely workable non-automated solution:

- Write different help files for different versions/version ranges *a la* `MyGreatProgram8.sthlp`, `MyGreatProgram14.sthlp`, etc.
- Write a "foyer" help file, `MyGreatProgram.sthlp`, which serves as a directory to version-specific help files *a la*:

  ```
  help MyGreatProgram
  -------------------------------------------------------

  Title
      MyGreatProgram -- Précis of MyGreatProgram

  Directory of MyGreatProgram documentation for
      [Stata v 8 to Stata v 13 users]
      [Stata v 14+ users]
  ```

Where `[Stata v 8 to Stata v 13 users]` links to `MyGreatProgram8.sthlp`, and `[Stata v 14+ users]` links to `MyGreatProgram14.sthlp`.